# How can I Push only unique values into a array in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have a like table. and in that like table I have a array called videoLikes. I need to store the userData who had liked the video. so when I am trying to push an object with userId field into that array I got duplicate datas. my userId is unique on model so I need to push only a user once in that array. I have tried $addToSet operation but it's not working properly.

**My usecase is when a user tried to like the video second time it won't push to that array.**

```
{
  "videoId": 275,
  "likesCount": 4,
  "videoLikes": [
    {
      "userId": 149,
      "uid": "5B8slS9AqpeNMJWK5CgbwzdXhQ82",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "625569ecd56d19a1954f5cc2"
      }
    },
    {
      "userId": 149,
      "uid": "5B8slS9AqpeNMJWK5CgbwzdXhQ82",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "625569ecd56d19a1954f5cc4"
      }
    },
    {
      "userId": 149,
      "uid": "5B8slS9AqpeNMJWK5CgbwzdXhQ82",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "625569ecd56d19a1954f5cc0"
      }
    },
    {
      "userId": 149,
      "uid": "5B8slS9AqpeNMJWK5CgbwzdXhQ82",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "625569ecd56d19a1954f5cbe"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you should normalize the schema as when you know userId you know uid, this way you only have to store userId in array which is a integer and can be easily handled to make it unique.
- you probably wanna learn about pre and post in mongoose and triggers in mongoDB.

using triggers you'll get time to check whether the user liking is previously done or not and perform action on its behalf.
for checking whether a userId liked or not you can use Object instead of array
example:

```
let schema=mongoose.Schema{
   videoId:Number,
   likesCount:Number,
   videoLikes={{uid:Number}}
}
```

Comment: sorry i need to store it in a array

Comment: you can use array just replace {{uid:Number}} with [{uid:Number}] .
I have suggested it because of O(1) time checking if the user has liked or not.